# HttpContext Items Not Available to Web Method Called by AJAX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, httpcontext

I have an item that I store in the HttpContext:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["myItem"] = "123";
```

I can access this no problem from any of a page's methods.  For example:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    string l_myItemVal = HttpContext.Current.Items["myItem"] as string; // "123"
}
```

This works fine.

However, when calling one of the page's web methods via AJAX, this fails:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static string MyWebMethod()
{
    string l_myItemVal = HttpContext.Current.Items["myItem"] as string; // NULL
}
```

Is the HttpContext of an asynchronous call different from the HttpContext for the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) only holds items *during a single request*. Your AJAX request is a second request, and has it's own `Items` property.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to enable session state to make this work:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]
```

Comment: @Ray: -1. Session state has nothing to do with `HttpContext.Items`

Comment: that is true - I suggested it as an experiment to see if it would allow access to HttpContent - wouldn't be the first time that we saw unexpected/unintended consequences. I read his problem to be accessing the HttpContext itself. Your answer (items relevant to one request only) is probably correct.